# I get this error when I try to load the Maps extension. How can I fix it?

Tags: server, 18.04, mediawiki

The error message is:

```
 MapsRegistration::onRegistration' is not callable in /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/registration/ExtensionRegistry.php:
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve an error like this, you'd need to update the dependencies of the

"composer.lock" file. So, run `composer update`, and reboot Ubuntu. It should fix the issue.